# Doctrine not detecting changes on a custom type extending ObjectType

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to use a custom Doctrine type made by a vendor. The vendor uses this type and it works well. However I am having issues using it. The type is [`JMSPaymentCoreBundle's ExtendedData`](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSPaymentCoreBundle/blob/master/Entity/ExtendedDataType.php). I use it in an entity following:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Entity\ExtendedData;

/**
 * Class Customer
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="customers")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\ChangeTrackingPolicy("DEFERRED_EXPLICIT")
 */
class Customer {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var ExtendedData
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="extended_data", type="extended_payment_data")
     */
    private $extendedData;
    private $extendedDataOriginal;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->extendedData         = new ExtendedData();
        $this->extendedDataOriginal = clone $this->extendedData;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostLoad()
     */
    public function onPostLoad() {
        $this->extendedDataOriginal = clone $this->extendedData;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function onPreSave() {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();

        // this is necessary until Doctrine adds an interface for comparing
        // value objects. Right now this is done by referential equality
        if (null !== $this->extendedDataOriginal && false === $this->extendedData->equals($this->extendedDataOriginal)) {
            $this->extendedData = clone $this->extendedData;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return ExtendedData
     */
    public function getExtendedData() {
        return $this->extendedData;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt() {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }
}
```

The callbacks and entity properties like the `DEFERRED_EXPLICIT` change tracking policy were copied from an entity that is present in JMSPaymentCoreBundle [here](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSPaymentCoreBundle/blob/master/Entity/PaymentInstruction.php).

The actual issue that I am having is that Doctrine will not detect any changes made to the ExtendedData in my entity. I have `DEFERRED_EXPLICIT` as a change tracking policy and I explicitely persist the Customer entity but the callback that (I presume) forces Doctrine to see the changes in `extendedData` isn't called, since the entity isn't going to be persisted as Doctrine has no changes. Changes are done by doing stuff like `$customerInstance->getExtendedData()->set('key', 'value')`.

I did some digging into Doctrine's `UnitOfWork` and I think that when the entity is loaded from the database, the `originalEntityData` references the `ExtendedData` instance, and so when I do a modification in a controller, the instance in `originalEntityData` is also changed, so in `UnitOfWork::computeChangeSet`, the original data is equal to the new data, and nothing is changed. I guess it'd work if I had a dummy column in my entity that I'd modify before each persist operation, which would then "force" the call to the preSave callback, but I'd rather not clutter my entity.

Is there a way to make this work other than the dummy column ?